# Users can't access their samba shared homes from Windows

Tags: samba, users, share, home-directory

I installed and configure a Samba 4 as AD and I shared Homes. I can log in the Samba server and a Windows 2008 server with my users. However, on Windows, when I type "\IPSambaServer\user1" when logged with user1, I get access denied with error code : 0x80070005.

Of course I don't wan't a 777 on home directories and.

Linux permissions on Samba Server :
`ls -dl /home/user1
drwx------. 6 user1 users 4096 Aug 26 14:04 /home/user1/`

testparm :

> [global]
>   
> workgroup = DOMAIN
>   
> ream = enterprise.com
>   
> server string = Samba Server
>   
> server role = active directory domain controller
>   
> security = AUTO
>   
> passdb backend = samba_dsdb
>   
> log file = /usr/local/samba/var/log.samba
>   
> max log size = 50
>   
> dns proxy = No
>   
> rpc_server:tcpip = no
>   
> rpc_daemon:spoolssd = embedded
>   
> rpc_server:spoolss = embedded
>   
> rpc_server:winreg = embedded
>   
> rpc_server:ntsvcs = embedded
>   
> rpc_server:eventlog = embedded
>   
> rpc_server:srvsvc = embedded
>   
> rpc_server:svcctl = embedded
>   
> rpc_server:default = external
>   
> idmap config * : backend = tdb
>   
> map archive = No
>   
> map readonly = no
>   
> store dos attributes = Yes
>   
> vfs objects = dfs_samba4, acl_xattr
>   
>   [homes]
>   
> comment = Home Directories
>   
> read only = No
>   
> create mask = 0660
>   
> directory mask = 0771

I add the `user_xattr,acl` in my /etc/fstab

Weird thing is that administrator can access (read and write) to his home, and every user's homes. But maybe it's because I mapped root = DOMAIN\administrator

For test, I created dir /tmp/test with 777 rights then shared it. With my user1 from Windows I created a directory in it. Then `ls -l /tmp/test/` tell me the owner of the new directory instead of user1, is 3000040. I tried with an other user and it was 3000043.

In security tab of homes' share, "Creator and Propri" have read / write access.
How can I do to grant access to user's homes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution !

When a user was created, I used a script to add an uidNumber to Samba (with an ldif file and command ldbmodify). The problem was that Samba creates its own uidNumber (the "300040" for user1 in my case) and with a Windows machine used it for access rights.

The only way I find to get this number is with `wbinfo -i user1`. So I put for each users this number in the uidNumber and it works !